# Keyboard shortcuts on Flutter web

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, flutter-web

I'm adding keyboard shortcuts to a Flutter web application.

I have a form within a custom `FocusableActionDetector` where the shortcut has form like this:

```
SingleActivator(LogicalKeyboardKey.digit2)
```

and action is like:

```
CustomActivateIntent: CallbackAction<CustomActivateIntent>(
      onInvoke: (intent) { provider.value = "2"; },)
```

In the same form I have a couple of numeric `TextFormField`s. To permit writing the character "2" I have to put these text fields inside some new `FocusableActionDetector`, otherwise the previous detector catches the command and the text field loses the "2" character, and this is already quite weird... Moreover, after writing in any of the text fields the form focus detector doesn't work anymore.

I think this could be related to the focus system, which is yet not that clear to me.
Can anyone help find a clean solution?

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround: the `FocusableActionDetector` is now preceded by an if statement. The code looks like the following:

```
// I extract the form to a widget to make it clearer
var searchWidget = SearchWidget();
child: textEditingInProgress
    ? searchWidget
    : FocusableActionDetector(
        child: searchWidget,
        ...,
    ),
```

The `textEditingInProgress` bool is a field in a provider and is controlled by the `FocusNode`s belonging to the `TextController`s.

Still this is not a perfect solution, in particular I'd like to understand why the previous approach was not working.